Cannot launch snap store from VNC session on Ubuntu 22.04
I recently installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop on a Dell server I had, and I use it as a headless machine, accessed by VNC. I could not run many of the software offerings under VNC, in fact, I had to uninstall the snap version of firefox, and install the Mozilla repository to install a working version of Firefox.  Is there a way to get snap working under VNC, or is there another way to get various software repositories available as a GUI without snap?

another way to get various software repositories available as a GUI without snap -- Yes, use the APT versions

I ended up changing my xstartup in the .vnc folder to what is listed in this posting
How to get snap applications to run on a vnc session
After rebooting snap on vnc is working correctly.
